# WrapPanel grabs focus from its children

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight

I have some (homemade) controls in a wrappanel in a scrollviewer and I want my controls to get focus when I click on them or Tab through them. But the wrappanel grabs the focus and hands it to Children[0].

```
<ScrollViewer IsTabStop="False" >
   <toolkit:WrapPanel>
        <!-- children, filled in from code. IsTabStop="True" -->       
   </toolkit:WrapPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The scrollviewer did the same thing but its `IsTabStop="False"` made it behave. However, the WrapPanel does not have a `IsTabStop` property. So how can I make it stop grabbing focus from its children?

I tried to set focus 'manually', using `Focus()`, from a mouse click eventhandler in my controls. The control gets focus but the wrappanel grabs it right away and it ends up at Children[0], even though I attempt to stop the mouseclick event from bubbling up (`e.Handled = true`).

Comment: Maybe you can set the `IsHitTestVisible` property to `false`. I don't know if it helps...

Comment: @Rico Thanks. But IsHitTestVisible =false on the wrappanel inhibits mouseclicks on its children... Also, it doesnt seem to help, the Tab'ing still loses focus to the wrappanel.

Comment: hmm... I already thought that. And since the wrappanel doesn't have a `TabIndex` I am out of ideas. Sorry

Comment: You are on the wrong track. The `WrapPanel` is a `Panel` and therefore cannot have focus. Yes, theoretically it could set focus to some other control, but I doubt it. I had my share of focus issues and will try my very best to help you. My guess: your custom child controls do not fulfill all the [requirements for owning the focus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903954%28VS.95%29.aspx).

Comment: @Martin Thanks. I'll certainly follow up on your guess. About the wrappanel not having focus. You are right, but it does grab it and then it gives it to Children[0] even though I explicitly call Focus() on some other child. I've updated the question.

Comment: @BaBu: I'm curious, have you checked your custom control's implementation for focus readiness or the lack thereof?

Comment: @Martin I'm working on it... One thing I have learned is what you are implying; calling Focus() on a usercontrol will fail unless there is at least one control in there with TabStop=True. Also, a WrapPanel.GotFocus evenhandler can be hooked up, and it gets called, but it's propably a bad idea since the panel cannot hold focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow its working fine for me. sharing the code snippet of what I tried.

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Image Name="img" Height="100" Width="100"/>
        <TextBox Name="tb3" Text="text2" KeyDown="tb3_KeyDown"  Width="200"/>
    </Grid>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2">
    <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" Name="wp">

    </toolkit:WrapPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Adding textboxes from code behind

```
TextBox tb2 = new TextBox();
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.Text = "some text";
        tb.Width = 200;


        tb2.Text = "some text";
        tb2.Width = 200;

        wp.Children.Add(tb); 
        wp.Children.Add(tb2);

    }
```

Changing focus from one textbox inside grid to textbox inside WrapPanel

```
  private void tb3_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
if(e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Enter)
{
tb2.Focus();
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I replicated your example and it certainly does work. Sadly my application does not. But now I know it _can_ work, and I have something to compare with.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. After having cleaned up the custom-made user control and gained control of all the focus requirements (`IsTabStop`, ``, etc ) the WrapPanel still grabbed focus and handed it to its Children[0] after i explicitly set focus to one of the other children. Stopping the mouseclick event fixed it:

```
void UserControl_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs a)
{
   try
   {
       this.Focus();
   }
   finally
   {
       a.Handled = true;
   }
}
```